# Start intent from package which cannot extends Activity

Tags: java, android, json, http-response-codes

I have some problems handling http response codes. The problem is that the app crashes because I do not give a specific function to run.
In this case I want to send the user back to login screen when the `Httresponsecode` is `401` otherwise the user can still use the app.

**In my current code I have the following:**

```
public boolean isUnauthorized(JSONObject response){
    try {
        if(response.getInt("StatusCode") == 401) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I want is here is to call so that when calling this function app wide it will do the same on every screen.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Register.class, Register.activity);
startactivity(i);
```

However this isn't possible because the `ResponseHandler` cannot extends Activity. If I do this I get a stack-trace error containing looper.prepare() must be called.

Can you anybody tell me how I can call a new intent from here. The class containing above is in a folder called components and my app activities are in another folder in case it is needed for giving the right answer.

Comment: You'll need to pass the Activity context from the activity you're calling this class from, and then use that when you're creating a new intent i.e. Intent intent = new Intent(context, Register.class)

Comment: you have wrongly passed Context in place of Activity Classes name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the current Activity or the Application Context as argument for your Intent.

If it is inside a fragment then

```
getActivity().startActivity(getActivity(), newActivity.class);
```

If it is inside a class then:

```
context.startActivity(context, newActivity.class);
```

Comment: used the same method as described and now it works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Register.class, Register.activity);
startactivity(i);
```

This should be

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, Activity.class);
startactivity(i);
```

if you have fragment

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
getActivity().startactivity(i);
```